# vim-hdevtools: error message about ghc-mod root

Tags: haskell, vim, ghc-mod

Recently (after fixing my Haskell setup after upgrading to El Capitan), when I'm editing Haskell files for a moment in Vim, I get the following error:

```
"FPRef.hs" 13L, 316C written
syntastic: error: checker output:
You must run ghc-mod in the project directory as returned by `ghc-mod root`. Currently in: "/Users/mingtang/Code/FP15/src/FP15/Evaluator"but should be in "/Users/mingtang/Code/FP15".
syntastic: error: checker haskell/ghc_mod returned abnormal status 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Googling this error message leads to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/atom-haskell/haskell-ghc-mod/issues/50

Here is the version of my ghc-mod:

```
$ ghc-mod --version
ghc-mod version 5.4.0.0 compiled by GHC 7.8.3
```

I have `vim-hdevtools` installed, and its last commit is in 2012, so I can't ask them for help.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this: `:help 'syntastic_mode_map'`.

Comment: According to the changelog for 5.4.0.0: "ghc-mod(i) executable must now be run in project directory for commands other than `root`". Guess the workaround is to install ghc-mod-5.3.0.0 for now. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod-5.4.0.0/changelog

Comment: No.  The workaround is to stop running syntastic for filetypes you don't need to check with it.